# Symfony : Can I return null from Type / Form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity form with Symfony :

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       ...
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'LogicielBundle\Entity\FichierGroup',
            'intention' => $this->getName() . '_token'
        ));
    }
```

But in POST_SUBMIT event, I want to return null (no entity).
I tested this but not working :

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        .... my condition ...
        $event->setData(null);
    });
```

Can you help me ? Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please tell us why do you want to return null? What is the workaround?

Comment: If a form is mapped to an object, submitted and binded, why do you want to get null from it?

Comment: If something wrong, you can throw an exception, but not null. For validation you can use Asserts. Really, what is the workaround?

Comment: How it doesn't work? Throws an exception or what?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post you controller code?
Do you pass an object reference to `createForm`, or do you use `$form->getData()` ? In your case, you should stick to the second.

Try using SUBMIT event instead of POST_SUBMIT. As Symfony doc states it, "It can be used to change data from the normalized representation of the data.".

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can not change a submit form. (I may be wrong)

But if you want reset a form after submit, you can do it in your controller:

For example:

```
public function fooAction()
{
    ...
    $form = $this->getEntityForm($entity);

    ...
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        // Do something
        ...
        // Reset your form with null as entity
        $form = $this->getEntityForm(null);            
    }

    ...
    return $this->render(
        'yourfootwig.html.twig',
        [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ...
        ]
    );
}

protected function getEntityForm($entity = null)
{
    return $this->createForm(
        'Foo:MyType',
        $entity,
        [...]);
}
```

Of course, you must adapt it with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want change data passed to form entity, the event should be listened on is `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`. [As described in the official doc.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-submit-event)

Comment: Watch out, on PRE_SUBMIT you mdify data from the request, with which the form will be built. Then you are limited to fields that are in the form, you can't "nullify" the form globally here.